# Not recognized non existant file

Tags: python, windows, image, cmd

im getting a weird error using this code (part of a class):

```
from sys import path as workingDIR
from os import system, path

image = '' # some jpeg image data
keep = 0

DIR = workingDIR[0] + '\\image'
if path.isfile(DIR + '.jpeg'):                # adding numbers to end of file name like how windows prevents multiple files having the same name
    x = 2
    while path.isfile(DIR + ' (' + str(x) + ').jpeg'):
        x += 1
    DIR += ' (' + str(x) + ')'
DIR += '.jpeg'
f = open(DIR, 'w+b')
f.write(image)
f.close()
system(DIR)
system('pause')
if not(keep):
    remove(DIR)
```

cmd is telling me `'...\image' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` (ignore the `...`), which doesnt make sense, because DIR has already been changed to `...\image.jpeg` and yet it is getting `image`. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Why would we ignore the `...`? Do you want us to solve your problem for you or not?

Comment: you should post sample code that people can run directly to reproduce the error

Comment: @David Hefferman the `...` is one of my folders on my flashdrive, and i dont feel like putting that online. why does it matter? im not messing with a system file or anything. you can place the picture wherever you want.

@ kefeizhou the code is practically the same as workable code. you dont need to do anything except remove the `def ...` stuff, provide the data of the image, and get rid of the tabs

Comment: I made some edits so the above code runs on my box but i don't see any errors. So unless you can provide complete code that reproduce the error (which according to you is simple), I can't really help you ..

Comment: OK, but it wasn't clear to me that ... was meant to be a placeholder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra white space in the image filename - "..\image (1).jpeg"
so when you call system(DIR), "..\image" becomes the command and "(1).jpeg" is the first argument.

Comment: Good catch on the whitespace. @calccrypto why are you using `os.system` anyway? `subprocess` is more robust (and meant to replace `os.system`).